# How to remove inherited CSS from body

Tags: css

I am trying to make some pages responsive but in doing so i am facing one issue. there are some css which are inherited by body. and i am not able to override it.

```css
fieldset[Attributes Style] {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-start: 2px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 2px;
  -webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
  -webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
  -webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
  min-width: -webkit-min-content;
  border: 2px groove threedface;
}
```

Above is the CSS which I don't want to be displayed. I tried overriding but was not able to make changes.

Please suggest if any idea to my problem.

Comment: Overriding is exactly what you need to do, you just need to make the rules more specific, eg. `#container fieldset { display: inline-block; }` etc. I've also retagged the question as it has nothing to do with HTML or jQuery

Comment: This is a good article for you to read about css and overriding rules: http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Answer (score 1):

These are the styles which the browser has for certain tags by default. You can overwrite them in your CSS:

```
fieldset {
  margin: 0; /* or any value you want */
  padding: 0; /* or any value you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the attributes you or rules specifically. Also, the '!important' overrides previously defined rules for example:

```
#fieldset{
   margin: 0 !important;
 }
```